# getting 2'complement of a binary number stored as a string in an input file

Tags: c++

I am a beginner. I am trying to get 2's complement of a binary number which stored in string 
`sou2_reg='000000000000000000000000000000011'`. If I will do `sou2_reg[32]` it gives me `1`, the last bit.

Now what I want to do is getting 2's complement of `sou2_reg`. I tried this but its not working. Can you please give me some piece of code?? Really appreciate

```
string twosComp(string number) {

     if ( number == 0 ) { return "1"; }
     if ( number == 1 ) { return "0"; }

     if ( number % 2 == 0 ) {
         return twosComp(number / 2) + "1";
     }
     else {
         return twosComp(number / 2) + "0";
     }
}
```

Comment: Use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: I think you can only do that by looping through the string and turning each 0 to 1 and 1 to 0, then add 1 (right before the end of the string). can't see how you can do something like number/2

Comment: can you please give me piece of code ?..I am really just a beginner.

Comment: My code only does the reverse not adding 1 .

Answer (score 1):

1) `%` doesn't work on a string

2) What your code does is find the one's complement. The two's complement is that plus one.

```
std::bitset <MYSIZE> bset(number);
bset.flip(); // one's complement
for (int i = 0; i < bset.size(); i ++) {
    if (bset[i])
        bset[i] = 0;
    else {
        bset[i] = true;
        break;
    }
}
return bset.to_string();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string twos_complement(std::string& number)
{
    for (auto it = number.begin(); it != number.end(); ++it)
    {
        auto& bit = *it;

        bit = (bit == '0') ? '1' : '0';
    }

    //  do adding logic here

    return number;
}
```

Comment: @vlad_tepesch I commented for him to do the adding logic below the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it using bit manipulation to avoid conditionals.

```
string twosComp(string number) {
  for (int i = number.length(), carry = 1; i-- > 0;) {
    number[i] = (number[i]^1)+carry; // flip the bit and add the previous carry
    carry = (number[i]&2)>>1;        // save the overflow in the carry variable
    number[i] &= ~2;                 // mask out the overflow 
  }
  return number;
}
```

Comment: you should start at `number.length()-1` and run to `i>=0`

Comment: @vlad_tepesch The i-- in the condition takes care of that.

Comment: No. You use the i to iterate over the string. your first loop iteration will start on the terminating '\0'-character and the last iteration will ignore the first (zero-index) character.

Comment: that you also forgot is: the string contains character '0' (0x30) and '1' (0x31) and not binary 0 and 1. while flipping bits will still work, your carry handling is wrong.

Comment: I suggest you try stepping through the code in a debugger to see how it works. i is initialised to number.length(), then the it is compared against zero, then decremented (becoming number.length()-1), then the body of the loop is executed with the correct initial value. At the other end, i becomes 1, it's compared against 0 and this is the last time it matches that comparison, it's decremented to 0, and then the loop body is executed with the correct final value.

Comment: As for the string containing characters, I did not forget that. The carry handling is done by masking off bit 2 which is completely unaffected by the fact that you're dealing with characters considering their 2nd bit is always zero. Again I suggest you try stepping through the code and looking at the results. It does work.

Comment: ok, sorry you are right. the sideeffect in the compare confused me.
The carry math is also ok, because the 2nd bit is not set on '1'.
Shame on me - can you make an edit to your post, so that i can chagne the vote to up.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate that you gave a reason for your downvote and gave me a chance to explain myself. Hopefully the comments will make things clearer for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and iterative implementation of this could be.

```
char* complement2(char binaryString[])
{
   int i = 0;
   char *output = (char *)malloc((strlen(binaryString) + 1) * sizeof(char *));

   for(i = 0; binaryString[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      output[i] = binaryString[i] ^ 1;
   }
   output[i] = '\0';

   return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string is an array and you will have to treat each bit (stored as a char in your case) individually.  The best option for you will be to iterate over it converting the bits and as a final step, iterate using the addition with carry bit.  Think about how you will do it manually on paper and translate that to code using a string of chars.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string twos_complement(std::string number) {
    bool carry = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); ++i) {
        if (!carry)
            number[i] = number[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        else if (number[i] == '0') {
            number[i] = '1';
            carry = false;
        }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone I got my answer. This post was really very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For reference about representing 2's compliment in C++ using bitset: http://2scomplimentcpp.blogspot.com.au/